# Get values that are only in one of two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to fetch records that are not available in one of two tables. Say I have table A with:

```
100
120
140
```

and table B with:

```
100
110
130
```

I want to fetch the values that appear in either table but not in both:

```
120
140
110
130
```

Comment: I tried two seprate queries like

select id from table a 
minus 
select id from table b


select id from table b
minus 
select id from table a

Comment: From the Oracle documentation: "To write a query that performs an outer join and returns all rows from A and B, extended with nulls if they do not satisfy the join condition (a full outer join), use the FULL [OUTER] JOIN syntax in the FROM clause."

Comment: I just want those records that are not exist in any one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of three ways off the top of my head, there are probably others. Closest to what you attempted, I think, combining the two separate queries you ran:

```
select num from a
minus select num from b
union all
(
  select num from b
  minus select num from a
);
```

Or only hitting each table once::

```
select num
from(
  select num from a
  union all
  select num from b
)
group by num
having count(*) < 2;
```

Or:

```
select coalesce(a_num, b_num)
from (
  select a.num a_num, b.num b_num
  from a
  full outer join b on b.num = a.num
)
where a_num is null or b_num is null;
```

All three produce the same result with your data. Demo of one using CTEs to provide your values:

```
with a (num) as (
  select 100 from dual
  union all select 120 from dual
  union all select 140 from dual
),
b (num) as (
  select 100 from dual
  union all select 110 from dual
  union all select 130 from dual
)
select coalesce(a_num, b_num) as num
from (
  select a.num a_num, b.num b_num
  from a
  full outer join b on b.num = a.num
)
where a_num is null or b_num is null;

       NUM
----------
       110
       130
       140
       120
```